# Arrange column with both numeric and hyphenated values

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to arrange a column with values like:

```
6-3
11-1
3
8-5
5
6-2
1
7
11-4
8-12
2
```

I want them to be arranged like this:

```
1
2
3
5
7
6-2
6-3
8-5
8-12
11-1
11-4
```

I have this query now:

```
select column_name from database_name.dbo.table_name
order by
(case when (BOX_NO not like '%-%')
then -1 when (BOX_NO like '%-%')
then cast(SUBSTRING(reverse(BOX_NO), LEN(BOX_NO)-(CHARINDEX('-', reverse(BOX_NO))-2), 0) as int) end),
(case when (column_name not like '%-%')
then cast(column_name as int)
when (column_name like '%-%')
then cast(SUBSTRING(column_name, LEN(column_name)-(CHARINDEX('-', reverse(column_name))-2), 8000) as int) end)
```

I'm going crazy. If anyone could help me that would be nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woopsy daisies! Everything's fine now. The first Case was wrong. There shouldn't have been a second reverse. And the search should start at 8000 and not 0. My bad!

```
(case when (column_name not like '%-%') then 0 when (column_name like '%-%') then cast(SUBSTRING(reverse(column_name), LEN(column_name)-(CHARINDEX('-', column_name)-2), 8000) as int) end),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @test table ( value varchar(10))

insert @test values ('6-3'),
    ('11-1'),
    ('3'),
    ('8-5'),
    ('5'),
    ('6-2'),
    ('1'),
    ('7'),
    ('11-4'),
    ('8-12'),
    ('2')

select 
    T2.value,
    case when CHARINDEX('-', T1.value) = 0 then cast(T1.value as int) else cast(LEFT(T1.value, CHARINDEX('-', T1.value) - 1) as int) end,
    case when CHARINDEX('-', T1.value) = 0 then 0 else cast(substring(T1.value, CHARINDEX('-', T1.value) + 1, 10) as int) end
from @test T1, @test T2
where T1.value = T2.value
order by 2, 3
```